# Pass Enum in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am making a custom FXML component. What I want to do it pass an Enum to the component so that it can retrieve all the values from the Enum. Here is a snippet of the custom component:

```
public ChoiceBoxSetting(@NamedArg("values") Enum values) {
    choiceBox.getItems().setAll(values.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants());
```

And here is the FXML creating it:

```
<ChoiceBoxSetting>
    <values>
        <MyCustomValues/>
    </values>
</ChoiceBoxSetting>
```

And here is the `MyCustomValues` enum:

```
public enum MyCustomValues {
    HI, HELLO, ME
}
```

So when I run it, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: MyCustomValues is not a valid type.
```

I am trying to pass the enum it's self, **not** one of the enum values, such as `MyCustomValues.HI`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element whose name corresponds to a class name is an instruction to the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate that class; so

```
<MyCustomValues/>
```

will cause the `FXMLLoader` to attempt to invoke `new MyCustomValues()`, which of course it cannot do with an enum type.

Ideally, you would want to pass in the actual `Class` object itself here, but as I can see no way to instantiate a `Class<?>` in FXML, I think the best you can do is to pass the name of the class. For example:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;

public class EnumChoiceBox<E extends Enum<E>> extends ChoiceBox<E> {
    
    public EnumChoiceBox(@NamedArg("enumType") String enumType) throws Exception {
        Class<E> enumClass = (Class<E>) Class.forName(enumType);
        getItems().setAll(enumClass.getEnumConstants());
    }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import application.EnumChoiceBox?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <EnumChoiceBox enumType="application.MyCustomValues"/>
</StackPane>
```

(replacing `application` with the actual package name of `MyCustomValues`).

---

## Update

Contrary to what I believed eight years ago, this is actually possible with the initial setup in the question. All that is required to be passed is one value from the enum (not the enum class itself), and this can be done using `fx:constant`:

```
<ChoiceBoxSetting>
    <values>
        <MyCustomValues fx:constant="HI"/>
    </values>
</ChoiceBoxSetting>
```

The choice of which value to pass is arbitrary.

Comment: It's sad that you can't pass a `Class`, but this works. Thank you!

Comment: Well, even if you could, the only way you could create one in FXML is by specifying the class name as a `String` anyway, so you really haven't lost much. You could define an overloaded constructor taking a `Class<E extends Enum<E>>` for use from Java code, if you wanted.